# WPF and WCF Install x509

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, x509

I have created a WCF service that uses a x509 test certificate.  I have also created a WPF application that calls the service.  The WCF service is hosted on IIS and the WPF client will run from remote users.  In testing the WPF application runs fine when I install the test cert. on the end users PC.

I have 2 questions before I move to production:

1. where is the best place to purchase and or create a x509 certificate?  We would like it to be valid for 10 + years so we don't have to replace the WPF client every 3 years.
2. How do we install the x509 when the WPF client is installed?  Right now if I manually add the certificate to the trusted root on the end users pc everything runs fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by changing the Identity value

```
 <identity>
      <dns value ="myssl.domain.com"/>
    <!--<certificate encodedValue=XXXXXX" -->
    </identity>
```